# Access/Excel: How to do this sequence of tasks?

Tags: excel, batch-file, ms-access, save

I am so lost on how to do a sequence of tasks and I don't even know where to begin on this and I feel like it could be done with a script or etc.

**Task I wish to perform**

1. Extract data from a table on Access based on the month/year.

   ```
       Example: It is November 1st, 2017 and I want Access to take data 
                from only October 2017 and nothing else. Then next month 
                December 1st, 2017 and it takes data from November 2017
   ```
2. Then I want that data to go to Excel and then export as .xlsx with the Month/year in it

   ```
       Example: "October2017Datasheet.xlsx"
   ```

**Keynotes / What I understand so far**

- You can use Window's Task Scheduler to automate some of the tasks
- I want the whole process to be automated somehow

*Thanks for any help you can give it is much appreciated*

Comment: Batch files cannot interact with graphical user interface programs.

Comment: @squashman that's just not true. You can start a specific macro from a batch file (and using powershell, you can do much more)

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth that is not interacting with a graphical user interface. That is starting an executable which pretty much any scripting language can do. The batch file cannot do anything besides launching the executable. It cannot control input or output into the interface.

Comment: You could use task scheduler to run a spreadsheet that is configured to pull the data from the Access database and then export it.  You'll have to write some code in VBA or whatever other scripting languages Excel supports these days.

Comment: You should review [Ask] and [MCVE].  You don't seem to have a coding question here.

Comment: Please change the question title: `Write code for me plz.`

Comment: @SteveFest that was never really my intention just more wanted to know how to approach this

Answer (score 0):

Use the *CopyFromRecordset* method in Excel to retrieve the data into a new workbook.

Filter these on:

```
DateDiff("m", [YourDateField], Date()) = 1
```

Save your new workbook giving it the name:

```
Format(DateAdd("m", -1, Date()), "mmmmyyyy") & "Datasheet.xlsx"
```

Insert code in your workbook to run the code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    FunctionToImportData()
    FunctionToSaveWorkbook()

    Application.Quit

End Sub
```

Now, use the *task scheduler* of Windows to run Excel and your workbook once every month.

Comment: OP likely does not know what any of these VBA/SQL lines mean. Consider fleshing out.

Comment: @Parfait: That may be too much. I replied to: _that was never really my intention just more wanted to know how to approach this_